# Two flights delay? or two flight delays?

Tags: word-order

If I would like to say that one airline stated that there were two flights delay due to an engine failure, should it be “two flight delays”? or “two flights delay”?

Comment: It's "*two flights were (or are) delayED*". But it would be better to ask these types of questions on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: It's the same as if you wanted one bread roll for yourself, and another for your friend. You'd ask for ***two bread rolls***, not ***two breads roll***. But as @Dan says, this is at best an ELL question.

Comment: @FF--just mentioning, in the US, "bread rolls" are just "rolls."

Comment: Two flight delays.

Comment: Or, they might have said *there were two flights delayed*.  Perhaps the D wasn't clearly pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

### One possible scenario

The failed airplane is one of a pair of planes that shuttle between London and Paris.  Normally, London-to-Paris flights leave at 8 am, 9 am, 10 am, 11 am, etc.  However, due to the malfunction, passengers that were scheduled to be on the 8 am flight are now going to depart at 10 am.

I would call that a *two-flights' delay*.  That is, there was one delay of a duration equal to two flights.

### Another scenario

The airplane, while parked at the gate, was discovered to be faulty.  Therefore, the passengers on that flight had to be rebooked for a later flight.  Furthermore, because it was stuck at the gate, it blocked a second airplane from using the gate at its scheduled time slot, causing the second plane's arrival to be delayed as well.

I would then say that one engine failure caused *two flight delays*, or that it led to *two delayed flights*.